# How can I set 'fit to screen' as the default behaviour when changing my desktop background (wallpaper)

Tags: macos, desktop, wallpaper

Every time I want to set a picture as my desktop background it sets it so big that half of it is gone. I then have to go to the settings and choose desktop then choose a setting.

It is so annoying to have to go into settings every time I change a wallpaper!

Is there a way to set it so that whenever I right click and scroll to set a wallpaper, that it will automatically make it fit to screen?

Comment: what are your settings, Fill Screen, Fit to Screen, Stretch,...ect

Answer (score 1):

Go to system preferences, then "desktop & screen saver", then select the image. You should see a dropdown menu that allows you to "fit to screen."

Comment: But, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466528/wallpaper-reset-to-fill-screen-on-log-out.