# Wallpaper reset to "Fill Screen" on log out

Tags: settings, wallpaper

How can I stop my wallpaper getting reset to "Fill Screen" every time I log in?
I have to keep going to settings, select an image, set it to "Fit to Screen", then switch back to auto-rotate, random.
It seems to happen at random on either or both of my internal and external displays.
Ventura/M2

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to change unrelated, hidden settings:

Monterey:  > System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver > Monterey Graphic: *Anything except Dynamic*

Ventura:  > System Settings > Wallpaper > Dynamic Wallpapers > *select one* > Ventura Graphic: *Anything except Dynamic*

Then set it back to what you wanted, e.g. auto-rotate.
My settings are still the same after a couple of restarts.
A bug, surely.